# Eclipse ADT 'Couldn't resolve resource' but works fine

Tags: eclipse-adt

I realised today that you don't have to have string values in 'strings.xml', dimensions in 'dimens.xml', etc and you can put them in any xml file or indeed combine them all into one. As long as they are findable in the res folder and match the correct xml element format.

However, while this works fine and runs, Eclipse gives me an error 'Couldn't resolve resource' in the activity view when I try and use a value from the above, but it works just fine. Does Eclipse only search known file names or am I not doing something to get it to work.

I appreciate this may not be the recommended approach but I actually found this method in Reto Meier's Android development book, and I figured if he is one of the engineers it must be ok to do so :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, in the @prefix/varname you put the name of the file as the prefix, e.g. if the file was called bob.xml and the variable was called name it would be @bob/name.